# Python: Remove pair of duplicated strings in random order

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a list as below

```
[('generators', 'generator'), ('game', 'games'), ('generator', 'generators'), ('games', 'game'), ('challenge', 'challenges'), ('challenges', 'challenge')]
```

Pairs `('game', 'games')` and `('games', 'game')` are kind of same but they are in different order.

The output I am trying to achieve

```
[('generators', 'generator'), ('games', 'game'), ('challenge', 'challenges')]
```

How can I remove pairs as such from above list ?

Any suggestions, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will your tuple consist of only two elements?

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @BlackThunder, Yes each pair contains only two elements, always.

Comment: this would remove every item from this list, correct?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede, if item refer to pair of strings, yes. I am trying to remove similar pair.

Comment: Wait, so the result would be an empty list? Please update your question with the desired output to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thats what im saying I have the empty list solution thats what it should be since all items in the list follow this patter

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I have updated the output I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an unordered hashable data structure within a set. `frozenset()` is your friend here:

```
In [7]: {frozenset(i) for i in your_list}
Out[7]: 
{frozenset({'generator', 'generators'}),
 frozenset({'game', 'games'}),
 frozenset({'challenge', 'challenges'})}
```

Note that in order to avoid looping over your list it's better to do this at the first place while creating your list.

Comment: this answer is good, but would be better migrated in the duplicate link (where there's already a good, different answer)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think in such cases it's better to mark the other one as duplicated. That answer is terrible tho. At least for cases were items in tuples (sub-sets) are not equal.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd would you apply this process if the object type needed to be maintained? So if you needed `list(set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in your_list))`?

Comment: What do you mean by ` the object type needed to be maintained`? We don't do anything to object type. Also, your code is completely different than this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the list and then take every other index using *list comprehension*

```
lista = [i for i in sorted(tups)[::2]]
# [('challenge', 'challenges'), ('game', 'games'), ('generator', 'generators')]
```